# Create table using attributes from other tables, as well as new attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an ER Diagram where I have 2 entities connected by a relationship that has an attribute, that looks a little like this: [image: ERD]

I can create a new table with:

```
CREATE TABLE participate AS (
  SELECT user.id, group.group_id 
  FROM user, group
)
```

I am unsure how to also add the `date` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend being explicit with a `cross join` rather than `,`.

You can just add the date:

```
CREATE TABLE participate AS (
  SELECT u.id, g.group_id, current_datetime as date 
  FROM user u CROSS JOIN
       group g;
```

`USER` and `GROUP` are really bad choices for table names, because the are SQL keywords and reserved words. I usually name tables in the plural, so I would recommend `USERS` and `GROUPS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a dummy value:

```
CREATE TABLE participate 
AS 
SELECT user.id as user_id, 
       group.group_id, 
       current_date as "date"
FROM "user"
  CROSS JOIN "group";
```

---

Note that `user` and `group` are reserved keywords. You should avoid using them as table names. But if you do, you have to enclose them in double quotes every time you use that table